# Get commit history of all the contributors of a repository

Tags: api, github

Is there a way to get the commit history of all the contributors of a git repo with lines added,deleted.

Currently the statistics api provides the stats of top 100 contributors, but not everyone.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/
(https://api.github.com/repos/saltstack/salt/stats/contributors

Answer (score 1):

You won't get more than 100 through the GitHub API alone: see "[How can I get more than 100 results from GitHub API v3 using “github_api” gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190375/6309)".
The results are capped at 100.

You would need top clone the repo, and then [show the number of changed lines per author in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787253/6309).
or use a tool like [gitinspector](https://github.com/jbnicolai/gitinspector):

[image: http://wiki.gitinspector.googlecode.com/git/images/html_example.jpg]