# How to retrieve all the contributors of a repo using github api

Tags: java, api, curl, github

I'm trying to get the all contributors of a repo using this [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors).

If I'm not wrong,it also tells me, if there are more than 500 contributors for a repo, it only gives 500 of them  and rest are marked as anonymous.

> For performance reasons, only the first 500 author email addresses in the repository will be linked to GitHub users.

This repo [linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) has 5k+ contributors, as per the api i should get at least 500 contributors through the api.

When i do `curl  -I https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/contributors?per_page=100`

I get only 3 pages (per_page = 100) so i get >300 contributors.(look at "link" header)

Is there a way to get all the contributors of the repo ( 5000+ )?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 18:00:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 100308
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1447958881
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:06:38 GMT
ETag: "a57e0f74fc68e1791da15d33fa044616"
Vary: Accept
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
Link: <https://api.github.com/repositories/2325298/contributors?per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/2325298/contributors?per_page=100&page=3>; rel="last"
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: a30e6f9aa7cf5731b87dfb3b9992202d
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 67E881D2:146C9:24CF1BB3:564E0E55
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148490/how-can-i-get-more-than-100-results-from-github-api-v3-using-github-api-gem

Comment: @simplyblue Try ?anon=1

Answer (score 4):

Since the GitHub API doesn't seem to support this, another approach (a much much slower approach) would be to clone the repo and then run this command (to get names):

```
git log --all --format='%aN' | sort -u
```

To get results by email address (which should guard against contributor name config changes and will be more accurate):

```
git log --all --format='%aE' | sort -u
```

If you needed this functionality for any repo you could write a simple script that would take in the repository path, clone the repo, run the command, and then delete the downloaded repo.

In the meantime, you could [contact GitHub](https://github.com/contact) in hopes they increase the priority in expanding/fixing their API.

Comment: This is infinity slower than using the GitHub API. There is a much better way by iterating through the contributors list.

Comment: @Whitecat But the Github API have not all information, then this is the current unique way to do that.